# Area Chart Gradient Fill Colour

Tags: excel, vba, charts, area

[image]

[image]

Dear all, I am trying to set the colour of the second chart to be the same as that of the first chart. Unfortunately, even manually without vba, I cannot seem to recreate the first chart's grey gradient colour effect. Any advice would be appreciated as to how i can alter the colour of the second chart to be as that of the first chart.

Comment: What kind of Chart are you using? MsChart? Excel?

Comment: This area chart is being plotted on Excel